# Redirect /index to /home

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

I currently have this rewrite rule in my .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^index/([^/]*)/?$ /index.php?user=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^index/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?user=$1&sort=$2 [L]
```

I want to redirect the above `/index` to `/home`, where the parameters also need to be considered. How can I do this?

Comment: @anubhava Yes. What other redirect is there?

Comment: ok hope below answer works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your rules to:

```
RewriteRule ^index/(.*)$ /home/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^home/([^/]*)/?$ /index.php?user=$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^home/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?user=$1&sort=$2 [L]
```